# EXTjs - How do I add headers: {'Content-Type':'charset=UTF-8;','accept-charset':'UTF-8'} in getForm().submit

Tags: extjs

I have already tried this

```
form.submit({
    url: url ,
    headers: {'Content-Type':'charset=UTF-8;','accept-charset':'UTF-8'},
    params:{
        data:data,
    },
    success: function (form, action) {}, 
    failure: function (form, action) {}, 
    scope: this
});
```

but its not working

I want to this for File uploading functionality in case of unicode characters 
In case of file upload unicode character are converted into 
"राध";

Comment: Check out XMLHttpRequest decision here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735403/how-to-add-authorization-header-in-ajax-request-in-extjs/78160551#78160551

Answer (score 2):

"Note: Headers are not sent during file upload."

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.action.Submit.html#cfg-headers