# How to add Authorization header in ajax request in extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload a file in ExtJS and web API. For that purpose, I need to send an authorization header to the server, but whenever I try to do so I get a null value in the header. I have also tried sending a header with XHR request in the `beforerequest` function, but I still got a null value.

Here is the code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'url',
            method: 'Post',
            headers : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token},
            form: form,
            isUpload: true,
            params: {id: id},
```

I have read somewhere that it's not possible to send a header in form submit. So is there any way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Use a normal form submit instead of Ajax and also try setting 'default headers' in your request.

Comment: @diamond421 have you tried without header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData object and XMLHttpRequest like this to upload files:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.open('POST', url, true);

 var formData = new FormData();

 for (var i= 0; i< files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      formData.append(file.name, file);
 }

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(eOpts) {
      if (xhr.readyState !== 4 || me.isDestroyed) {
            return;
      }
      ......
 };

 xhr.send(formData);
```

More about [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: There is no issue in uploading file, the only issue is I can't send headers to server even after using xhr

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting, but I also couldn't find ExtJS solution.

Here is an example how you can add headers to POST request with file published by [Gabriele Romanato](https://gabrieleromanato.name/javascript-file-upload-with-the-xmlhttprequest-object):

```
// Selects the input file from the HTML document
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");

// Creates an XMLHttpRequest instance
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// We set up the callback to handle the server response
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    // The file has been uploaded successfully
    console.log("File successfully uploaded!");
  }
};

// We open the connection to the server
xhr.open("POST", "/upload-file", true);

// We set the "Content-Type" header to "multipart/form-data"
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

// We create a FormData object and add the selected file
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);

// We send the request to the server with the send() method
xhr.send(formData);
```